# How to find the length of the binary file

Tags: r, binary

I have a binary file with size=2. But I want to read all the data into a vector and I don't how to find the total length of this binary data.

```
f <- file("a.bin", "rb")
readBin(f, integer(), size = 2, n = ??)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
file.info('a.bin')$size
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `x <- scan("a.bin", raw())` to read the entire file into a raw vector, then use `y <- readBin(x, integer(), n=length(x), size=2)` to convert the raw vector.

Each element in a raw vector is 4 bytes, so you may need to do some conversion to calculate the correct value for `n`.